# document .on click is multiplying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic function for drop down buttons, which are often loaded via AJAX. The basic idea is to click the button to toggle visibility on the dropdown content. *This part works.* But I also want the dropdown content to disappear when clicking elsewhere on the page. Here is the code:

```
 $(document).on({
     click: function() {

         var contentHolder = $(this).siblings("[class^=holder_dropdown]");

         if ($(contentHolder).is(":visible")) {

             // hide drop down
             $(contentHolder).hide();

         } else {

             // show drop down
             $(contentHolder).show();

             $(document).on({
                 click: function hideOnClick() {

                     console.log("clicked");
                     $(contentHolder).hide();
                     $(document).off('click', hideOnClick);

                 }
             });

         }

     }

 }, "[class^=dropdown]");
```

It works OK as it is in the sense that clicking elsewhere on the page does close the dropdown. However, I can see by writing to the console log that it keeps doing this even after the dropdown is hidden, which each additional click on the page until reloaded. This will become a memory sink for my site as the potential for this to expand and be firing off 100s of time is there.

What am I missing?

Comment: To track focus you could also use the `blur` `focus` `focusin` and `focusout` events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding an event handler inside another event handler. Event handlers are not *replaced*, they are *added*. So, after clicking on those specific elements twice, you added two event handlers that are responsible for hiding the dropdowns.

Make sure you unbind the event handler again:

```
function hideOnClick() {
    if ($(contentHolder).is(":visible")) {
        // hide drop down

        $(contentHolder).hide();
        console.log("dropdown hidden");

    }
    $(document).off('click', hideOnClick);
}

$(document).on('click', hideOnClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code need to look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    js_Codes();

    /* The rest of your code that will not reload after ajax request */

});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    /* Here we call the codes that will reload after your ajax request */
    js_Codes();
});

function js_Codes(){

    function clickOpenDialog(){
        $('.btOpenDialog').off('click',clickOpenDialog);
        fn_open_Dialog_Click($(this).prop('alt'), function(){$('.btOpenDialog').on('click',clickOpenDialog);});
        return false;
    };

    function fn_Open_Dialog_Click(myString){
        var myArray = myString.split(';');
        /* whatever u want with your page with a string param array */

    };

    $('.btOpenDialog').on('click',clickOpenDialog);
}
```

Enjoy it.. =]

Answer (score 0):

```
$("*[class^='dropdown']").on("click", function(){});
```

Comment: What does the problem have to do with event delegation? Why do you think *not* using event delegation fixes the problem?

Comment: the sintax $(ELEMENT).on("THE_EVENT", function(){});

Comment: Oh, you think the way the OP calls the function is incorrect? Not true. `.on` also accepts an object as first argument, and the selector can be passed as second argument. Have a look at the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data.

Comment: On the documentation say:
".on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )",
".on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )"
In the example:
$( "p" ).on( "myCustomEvent", function( event, myName ) {});
and!!!, $(document) is Wrong for the performance of your script.

Comment: And `".on( events [, selector ] [, data ] )"` is exactly what the OP is using here, so I don't understand the intention of your comment. Using `$(document)` is not "wrong", it's only better if you bind the delegated handler as close to the actual elements as possible. If you don't believe me, maybe this example will convince you: http://jsfiddle.net/qRrX2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.on( "blur", handler )`. It'll trigger only once when the dropdown goes out of focus.

Comment: blur won't work since focus is on the button not the dropdown holder